# How to differentiate NextAuth user signin and signup?

Tags: next.js, prisma, next-auth

I am building a blog platform using Nextjs 12, NextAuth(Google), Prisma(MySQL). When a user first signs up to my platform, NextAuth automatically saves user's google email address and google name to my database. I want to make user change their nickname when first signing up.

How would I know if the user is signing up or signing in? Currently in NextAuth, you click `signup()` button and you are good for both signup and signin..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would [extend](https://next-auth.js.org/adapters/prisma#create-the-prisma-schema) the base user model with a property such as `customName`, and then check on the front- or back-end whether the `customName` property is undefined/empty, and redirect or show a modal accordinglty.

You can perform the front-end check via `useSession`

```
const { data: session, status } = useSession()

if(status === "authenticated" && session.user.customName === ""){ // or whatever your default value for non-defined fields is

// Show your modal or redirect to the page where the user can change his username

// after user enters his new name, make an API call and update it in your DB
}
```

or on the back-end in `pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js`:

```js
...
callbacks: {
  async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
    if (user.customName) {
      return true
    } else {
      // User has no custom name yet, redirect him
      return '/pathWhereUserCanSetHisName'
    }
  }
}
...
```

If you want to ensure every user **has to** set a name before continuing, I would put the logic above into an API middleware or next's edge middleware like this:

For example, if you're using NextAuth JWT sessions via cookies, add a custom [cookie name](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#cookies) for the `sessionToken` and parse it within the next.js middleware:

`middleware.ts` (or .js)

```
export default async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
   const response = NextResponse.next();

   const userCookie = request.cookies.get(YOUR_CUSTOM_COOKIE_NAME) // the cookie name you set for NextAuth's sessionToken
   if(!userCookie){
     // user not logged in
    return NextResponse.redirect('/login')   
    }
   
   const user = yourCustomUserParsingFunction(userCookie) // parsing the JWT contained in the cookie
   if(user.customName){
     return response; // user has a custom name, don't intervene
   }

   // user has no customName, intervene
   return NextResponse.redirect('/pathWhereUserCanSetHisName');
}
```

Comment: Amazing! I think the second example you provided would fit perfectly for my case! Thanks:)